# echo form input field using substr_replace

Tags: php, input, replace, substr

I would like to replace a character in my string with a form input field but I can't seem to get it right

If i just replace the charcter with a * it works fine

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$charsGettingRemoved;$i++){
$charsRemoved[$i]=substr($word,$i,1);
$word = substr_replace($word,'*',$i,1);}
```

However when i try to put in an input field it all falls apart

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$charsGettingRemoved;$i++){
    $charsRemoved[$i]=substr($word,$i,1);
    $word = substr_replace($word,'<input type="text" name="question_1_letters[]" class="inputs" value="">',$i,1);}
```

I am probably missing something very obvious or maybe this is not possible using substr_replace, if anyone could give me some hints on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: try escaping the quote marks inside your string substitution

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible. You can't replace a string by html content using this function. You can try to add it in another way.

for exemple I will replace the word 'hello' by html element :

```
$string = "hey hello world!";
$tempstring = explode('hello',$string);
$newstring = $tempstring[0] . '<strong>html element<strong>' . $tempstring[1];
```